# How do I integrate a vrbo availability calendar on my own website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-calendar-api

I want to display availability on my property's website.   I have my vrbo and airbnb calendars synced with a Google calendar, however the Google calendar displays details that I don't want published on the website when embedded.  Looking for an API for the vrbo calendar or assistance with embedding the google calendar without the event names.

I have checked the box for "Show availability only" on the share settings for the Google Calendar but it still shows the event names.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We're not a product support network. You need to make an effort based on available documentation and provide code related to a _specific_ question.